# $P_{n,k} = \frac{S_{n,k}}{k!}.$ Partiton of integers and surjective functions.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Let $S_{n,k}$ denote the number of surjective functions from $[n] \to [k]$ and $P_{n,k}$ denote the number of partitions (integer) of $n$ into $k$ parts. To prove by combinatorial argument that $$P_{n,k} = \frac{S_{n,k}}{k!}.$$

---

My Argument:

Surjection is actually partitioning the set $[n]$ into $k$ parts, by defining where each element is going to. Since the map is a surjection none of the parts are empty. So it is a valid partition. But we can rearrange the elements and get a different surjective map but the cardinality of each preimage set is same. So we are diving a factor of $k!$.

---

Am I going wrong somewhere in the argument?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are wrong. The division by $k!$ takes out the order of the blocks, not the order of the elements in the domain of the function. So, for example, the set partition $\{1,2\},\{3\}$ gives you the integer partition $2,1$ but also this is given by $\{1,3\},\{2\}.$